# how to get bool value from List<object> in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, sqlclient

hi i am converting a vb project into c# from a youtube tutorial by mkaatr
he use a variable

```
 Private DBMSResultSets As List(Of Object)
```

so i use a variable in c# `private List<object> DBMSResultSets;`

and later in code he use a function with return type bool and he use a method

```
return DBMSResultSets(I).Read
```

so i use the same thing but visual studio give me error so hover on vb code `(DBMSResultSets(I).Read)`it say "get or set the element at the specified index"

so i look around and find out that if i write return `DBMSResultSets[(int)I]);` it do the same thing which is ("get or set the element at the specified index")

now visual studio give me error that can not convert object to bool so i use convert.to and also try the (bool) mean try to typecast but both method didn't work
so i need help
i am giving you the whole vb code and also my conversion c# code

> the problem is in function ReadAndNotEOF
>
> vb code

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    
    ' this class will be used to manage connectivity with the database
    Public Class DBMSClass
    
        ' define the connection string
        Private DBMSConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\LibraryManagementSystem\Database\LMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    
        ' define the connection
        Private DBMSConnectionObj As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    
        ' define the transaction
        Private DBMSTransactionObj As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction
    
        ' define the commands object and result sets
        Private DBMSCommands As List(Of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)
        Private DBMSCommandCodes As List(Of Long)
        Private DBMSResultSets As List(Of Object)
    
        ' command counter
        Private DBMSCommandCounter As Long
    
        ' open database connection
        Public Function OpenDB() As String
            Try
                ' open the connection
                DBMSConnectionObj = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.myconnection)
                DBMSConnectionObj.Open()
    
                ' create the transaction
                DBMSTransactionObj = DBMSConnectionObj.BeginTransaction
    
                ' prepare the commands list
                DBMSCommands = New List(Of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)
                DBMSCommandCodes = New List(Of Long)
                DBMSResultSets = New List(Of Object)
    
                ' prepare the command counter
                DBMSCommandCounter = 0
    
                ' return ok
                Return "OK"
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return ex.Message
            End Try
        End Function
    
        ' this is used to run sql commands
        Public Sub ExecuteSQL(ByVal SQL As String, ByVal ParamArray Obj() As Object)
    
            ' build the command object
            Dim CMD As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQL, Me.DBMSConnectionObj, Me.DBMSTransactionObj)
    
            ' add the parameters to the sql command
            Dim I As Integer
            For I = 0 To Obj.Length - 1
                CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & I, Obj(I))
            Next
    
            ' run the sql
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    
        End Sub
    
        ' this function is used to commit a transaction
        Public Sub Commit()
            Me.DBMSTransactionObj.Commit()
            Me.DBMSTransactionObj = Me.DBMSConnectionObj.BeginTransaction
        End Sub
    
        ' this function is used to rollback a transaction
        Public Sub Rollback()
            Me.DBMSTransactionObj.Rollback()
            Me.DBMSTransactionObj = Me.DBMSConnectionObj.BeginTransaction
        End Sub
    
        ' this function is used to create a result set
        Public Function CreateResultSet(ByVal SQL As String, ByVal ParamArray OBJ() As Object) As Long
            DBMSCommandCounter += 1
    
            ' build the command object
            Dim CMD As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQL, Me.DBMSConnectionObj, Me.DBMSTransactionObj)
    
            ' add the parameters to the sql command
            Dim I As Integer
            For I = 0 To OBJ.Length - 1
                CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & I, OBJ(I))
            Next
    
            ' read the data
            Dim RS = CMD.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default)
    
            ' store objects in list
            Me.DBMSCommandCodes.Add(DBMSCommandCounter)
            Me.DBMSCommands.Add(CMD)
            Me.DBMSResultSets.Add(RS)
    
            Return DBMSCommandCounter
        End Function
    
        ' this function is used to close a result set
        Public Sub CloseResultSet(ByVal Nmbr As Long)
            Dim I As Integer
            For I = 0 To Me.DBMSCommandCodes.Count - 1
    
                ' find the command and result set
                If DBMSCommandCodes(I) = Nmbr Then
    
                    ' get the objects
                    Dim R = Me.DBMSResultSets(I)
                    Dim C = Me.DBMSCommands(I)
    
                    ' remove the objects from the list
                    Me.DBMSResultSets.RemoveAt(I)
                    Me.DBMSCommands.RemoveAt(I)
                    Me.DBMSCommandCodes.RemoveAt(I)
    
                    ' return the resources
                    R.Close()
                    R.Dispose()
                    C.Dispose()
    
                    Return
    
                End If
            Next
    
            Throw New Exception("the command or result set does not exist")
        End Sub
    
        ' this function is used to read a single record from db
        Public Function ReadAndNotEOF(ByVal Code As Long) As Boolean
            ' do a search
            Dim I As Long
            For I = 0 To Me.DBMSCommandCodes.Count - 1
                If DBMSCommandCodes(I) = Code Then
                    Return DBMSResultSets(I).Read
                End If
            Next
            Throw New Exception("Command or Resultset does not exist")
        End Function
    
        ' this function is used to get a column value from db
        Public Function GetColumnValue(ByVal Code As Long, ByVal ColumnName As String) As Object
            Dim I As Long
            For I = 0 To Me.DBMSCommands.Count - 1
                If DBMSCommandCodes(I) = Code Then
                    Return DBMSResultSets(I).Item(ColumnName)
                End If
            Next
            Throw New Exception("Command or Resultset does not exist")
        End Function
    End Class
```

> my c# code

```
//this class will be used to manage connectivity with the database
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Library_main
{
    public class DBMSClass
    {
        //define the connection string

        // private String DBMSConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="\\D:\\tutorial\\c # tutorial\\3 may 2015\\Library_main\\Library_main\\bin\\Debug\\DataBase\\LMS.mdf";"Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        //define the connection
        private SqlConnection DBMSConnectionObj = null;
        //define the transaction
        private SqlTransaction DBMSTransactionObj;

        // define the commands object and result sets
        private List<SqlCommand> DBMSCommands;
        private List<long> DBMSCommandCodes;
        private List<object> DBMSResultSets;
        // command counter
        private long DBMSCommandCounter;

        //open database connection
        public string OpenDB()
        {
            try
            {
                //open the connection
                DBMSConnectionObj = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
                DBMSConnectionObj.Open();
                //creat the transaction
                DBMSTransactionObj = DBMSConnectionObj.BeginTransaction();
                //prepare the commands list
                DBMSCommands = new List<SqlCommand>();
                DBMSCommandCodes = new List<long>();
                DBMSResultSets = new List<object>();
                // prepare the command counter
                DBMSCommandCounter = 0;
                //return ok
                return "ok";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }

        //this is used to run sql commands
        public void ExceuteSQL(string SQL, params object[] Obj)
        {
            //build the command object
            SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(SQL, this.DBMSConnectionObj, this.DBMSTransactionObj);

            //add the parameters to the sql command
            int I;
            int count = Obj.Length - 1;
            for (I = 0; I <= count; I++)
            {
                CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + I, Obj[I]);
            }
            //run the sql
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        //this funtion to commit 
        public void Commit()
        {
            this.DBMSTransactionObj.Commit();
            this.DBMSTransactionObj = this.DBMSConnectionObj.BeginTransaction();
        }

        // this function is used to rollback a transaction
        public void Rollback()
        {
            this.DBMSTransactionObj.Rollback();
            this.DBMSTransactionObj = this.DBMSConnectionObj.BeginTransaction();
        }

        //this function is used to creat a result set
        public long CreatResultSet(string SQL, params object[] Obj)
        {
            DBMSCommandCounter += 1;
            // build the command object
            SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(SQL, this.DBMSConnectionObj, this.DBMSTransactionObj);

            // add the parameters to the sql command
            int I = 0;
            for (I = 0; I <= Obj.Length - 1; I++)
            {
                CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + I, Obj[I]);
            }
                // read the data
                dynamic RS = CMD.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default);

                // store objects in list
                this.DBMSCommandCodes.Add(DBMSCommandCounter);
                this.DBMSCommands.Add(CMD);
                this.DBMSResultSets.Add(RS);
            return DBMSCommandCounter;
        }

        // this function is used to close a result set
        public void CloseResultSet(long Nmbr)
        {
            int I = 0;

            for (I = 0; I <= this.DBMSCommandCodes.Count - 1; I++)
            {
                // find the command and result set

                if (DBMSCommandCodes[I] == Nmbr)
                {
                    // get the objects
                    dynamic R = this.DBMSResultSets[I];
                    dynamic C = this.DBMSCommands[I];

                    // remove the objects from the list
                    this.DBMSResultSets.RemoveAt(I);
                    this.DBMSCommands.RemoveAt(I);
                    this.DBMSCommandCodes.RemoveAt(I);

                    // return the resources
                    R.Close();
                    R.Dispose();
                    C.Dispose();
                    return;
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("the command or result set does not exist");
        }

        // this function is used to read a single record from db
        public bool ReadAndNotEOF(long Code)
        {
            // do a search
            long I = 0;
            for (I = 0; I <= this.DBMSCommandCodes.Count - 1; I++)
            {
                if (DBMSCommandCodes[(int)I] == Code)
                {
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(DBMSResultSets[(int)I]);
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("Command or Resultset does not exist");
        }

        // this function is used to get a column value from db
        public object GetColumnValue(long Code, string ColumnName)
        {
            long I = 0;
            for (I = 0; I <= this.DBMSCommandCodes.Count - 1; I++)
           
                if (DBMSCommandCodes[(int)I] == Code)
                {
                    return DBMSResultSets[(int)I].Equals(ColumnName);
                }
            
            throw new Exception("Command or Resultset does not exist");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should properly type your list, you aren't inserting Object but IDataReader.

Comment: `if (DBMSCommandCodes[(int)I] == Code)` is Code a string.. if so do the following 
`if (Convert.ToInt32(DBMSCommandCodes[I]) == Code)`

Comment: There's a lot of code here that is probably irrelevant to the problem. Have you tried creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: "but both method didn't work" - how do you know it did not work? Did you get an exception?

Comment: yes when i use the both method i got the exception @C.Evenhuis

Comment: @MethodMan no the code is type of long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of calling executeReader on an SqlCommand object is a `SqlDataReader`

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In this part of your code

```
// read the data
dynamic RS = CMD.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default);

// store objects in list
this.DBMSCommandCodes.Add(DBMSCommandCounter);
this.DBMSCommands.Add(CMD);
this.DBMSResultSets.Add(RS);
```

The type of RS is not the exact equivalent of a `ResultSet`like the accrostic suggests but it is a `SqlDataReader`which has a boolean method call `Read`and it will return true until there is no more datas to fetch from its stream

So here in your boolean method called `ReadAndNotEof`instead of

```
return Convert.ToBoolean(DBMSResultSets[(int)I]);
```

do

```
SqlDataReader reader = (SqlDataReader)DBMSResultSets[(int)I];
return reader.Read();
```

On the same pattern you can get the column value in your method GetColumnValue if your change:

```
return DBMSResultSets[(int)I].Equals(ColumnName);
```

by

```
SqlDataReader reader = (SqlDataReader)DBMSResultSets[(int)I];

object columnValue = reader[columnName];
return columnValue;
```

See [here on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy(v=vs.110).aspx) for the definition of the accessor `this` (brackets like reader[string_value]) that takes a string parameter (the column name)

Of course you need to be sure that the Read method of your SqlDataReader has returned true (your above method)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: it give me error that "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."     you can see my project here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx6QGIK0Sz0rVm5XT3lZMFhCRGM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @tjnapster555 I got it and will be analysing it: will be back asap

Comment: i share the whole code if you want to look at it  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx6QGIK0Sz0rVm5XT3lZMFhCRGM/view?usp=sharing            it say in function ReadAndNotEof  and its line                        SqlDataReader reader = (SqlDataReader)DBMSResultSets[(int)I];
return reader.Read();

Comment: i got the stack trace you can see it [link]http://codeviewer.org/view/code:50ae here i hope it might help . please tell me what is the problem its the only class is making problem after that all other 8 class depend on it . I really want to finish this project it will help me a lot to learn c#

Comment: @tjnapster555 let me look at the trace

Comment: @tjnapster555 in StaffClass.cs, right before line 128 there is a catch block. Change it to `catch (Exception ex)`and then just before line n# 128 add the following `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)`and then share the error message with me please. Note. If we keep a one to one talk SO will ask us soon to move into a chat room

Comment: i got this message "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."

Comment: sorry i got it i was so stupid the problem was i was not saving the data coz in tutorial  he say we don't need to commit the data but he didn't say that to check the test 05 which is "load the staff record from DB" we need data to be there. i Thought everything is happening virtually. thank you very much  alainlompo

Comment: @tjnapster555 my pleasure, and don't mind we all find ourselves in similar situation with programming. I am glad I could contribute a little bit. Wish you the best